# apt-get : Identify all old version numbers of a package?

Tags: php, debian, apt

I need to install PHP 5.3 on Debian.  If I were to perform a regular install of PHP I would get version 5.4.

I understand that I can run `apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>` to install a specific version.  But I don't know what the exact package version number is for PHP 5.3.

I've ran `apt-cache showpkg php5` and `apt-cache madison php5` but they only list the current version.

How can I identify the correct version number to use to install PHP 5.3?

Comment: Did you try the debian repository, since you want php5.3 then look at the squeeze repository since wheeze contains php5.5 I think. A related package I saw has this name php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze14_all.deb check for your self http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea if it's available in some apt command, but you can get the full list here: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/php5/

It seems the latest PHP 5.3 for Debian is 5.3.10-2: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/php5/5.3.10-2/

To install a package from snapshot, you have to add an entry to your /etc/apt/sources.list matching the packages you want, this entry can be found in the "pool" link. For instance, for php5 5.3.10-2 the pool link is http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20120221T041601Z/pool/main/p/php5/ so you need to add http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20120221T041601Z/ to you sources.list:

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20120221T041601Z/ unstable main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20120221T041601Z/ unstable main
```

> Those entries needs to be set to unstable, that's because snapshots give you the first time the packages apparead in the debian packages, and most often that's in unstable (but I guess it could be on experimental as well).

Next you need to update while telling apt to ignore packages expiration date:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

If you're using aptitude, that's:

```
aptitude -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Now you can install your specific version of php5:

```
apt-get install php5=5.3.10-2
```

Now, as you added an unstable repository to your installation, you may want to set priority to stable packages, see: http://www.imped.net/2007/07/20/apt-pinning-installing-unstable-packages-on-stable-debian/

Comment: Do you know how I would use this information to install PHP 5.3.10-2?  I thought I could just use `apt-get install php5=5.3.10-2` but it didn't work.  Neither did other version combinations I tried.

Comment: I edited my post to include some information on how to install a package from snapshots.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a glance.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer. Although it doesn't seem to work for me. If I `php -v` it shows a more revent version of the one I installed using `apt-get install php5=5.3.10-2`. If if `apt-cache policy php5` it however says the installed version if .5.3.10-2. Any idea? Thanks