# Alternative to storing PHP config values in php.ini

Tags: php

We have a web-app that we have modified a number of the default php.ini values for; `short_open_tag = Off`, `expose_php = Off`, `memory_limit = 128M`, etc, etc. Our current deployment strategy when we need to scale and bring another app server online involves cloning our app onto a 'new' server that has the latest version of php.ini, along with the distribution-specific (in our case, Debian) php.ini file.

We are currently storing our customized php.ini file in our repo and deploying that when we clone, but ran into a problem recently relating to deprecated config values when a new cloned app server fired up with PHP 5.4+ on it. This resulted in us having a broken config file, and got me thinking about how to best handle this. We'd like to use the default *latest* php.ini that would contain potentially new directives, and would have deprecated ones removed, and then be able to 'locally' override the settings we need.

Solutions we've considered include using `.htaccess` files and `ini_set()`, but three drawbacks here relate to the fact that [some settings can only be adjusted in php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), that .htaccess will not be used by our cli scripts, and that for each user visiting the site via Apache, we have to process the `.htaccess` or make calls to `ini_set()` resulting in unneeded overhead. We've also looked at freezing the version of PHP we use so that there are no updates and changes to php.ini once deployed, but I am not sure if this strategy works best, given we would miss out on minor updates that could be related to security, etc.

Have we missed an option as it relates to portably deploying PHP engine settings?

Comment: If you freeze the version of PHP to, say, 5.3 you shouldn't have problems between 5.3.14 and 5.3.15, etc. You should only see changes moving to 5.4.x.

Comment: Sounds like me you are trying to shoot for a moving target. WHich is generally a terrible idea. Just make sure all the versions are the same

Comment: You may store your values in the apache VirtualHost. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, as I was spilling my thoughts out above, this is where I started leaning. I am guessing that the 'cost' of running a possibly outdated version of PHP is far outweighed by the 'cost' of trying to hit said moving target.

Comment: Well it depends. For anything serious I target a specific version. For all my new stuff I target 5.5 and keep it on that. But please note that when you are (still) running 5.3 that it will be dead(ish) soon (next year). So you would be much better of doing tests with the application on 5.5 and see if you can start targetting that at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the direction provided by @PeeHaa above, we've decided to lock our application to a specific PHP version (via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)), taken that PHP version's default php.ini file for both Apache2 and the CLI, and added in our settings. This has then been pushed to our repo, and is copied as needed on deployment and on any git changes to the files.

FYI, in our Debian environment, we've followed the strategy [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128694/357801) in terms of installing a specific version of PHP other than latest.